# In a bit of a clash, need to write some quick and dirty object oriented code

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Ok, so I was recently put in charge of some really bad procedural-style code, and I need to write the rest of the site using PHP and being as object oriented as possible.

I have also decided that MVC would be the most logical ptatern to use, but I cannot find any true micro-related reading material or tutorials anywhere. The micro mvc will just have to take some input from a query string or whatever, and redirect the user to the views like a regular mvc, however I will not need all of that other functionality that is present in all the other frameworks. I also need to be able to fully customize it myself, which is why I am stuck. I simply just can't get to the writing stages. I don't know where to begin, or what to write.

A flow of how the app would work with my mvc code should be as follows:
Click on link from app -> redirected to a serve.php (or other, to serve up the file required) -> Send user to a view with a few inputs and outputs to/from the database.

I have problems writing the problem properly into words, it's just that I'm too much of an idiot to figure it out for myself, I guess.

Does anyone have any quick-and-dirty tips so I can get this prototype up and running?

Comment: Do you want to use a framework, or write this yourself? Question is unclear about this. There are loads of lightweight MVC micro-frameworks which would fit quite nicely. What are these "other functionality" that you don't want? _Also, what does this question have to do with CSS?_

Comment: Don't be so quick to throw away the existing code just because its not OOP.  Many huge applications such as Drupal work very successfully as a procedural app.

Comment: Yes, many does, but this one simply doesn't. It's a mess.